# Postfix calculation with stack class, C++

Tags: c++, stack

I am trying to use a custom stack class to calculate an equation in postfix form.  For some reason, the program keeps crashing.

Here is the stack header file

```
#ifndef aStack_h
#define aStack_h
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::string; using std::cout;
class aStack
{
    private:
        int top, size;
        int *stack;
    public:
        aStack(int s)
        {
            size = s;
            top = -1;
            stack = new int [s];
        }

        ~aStack() 
        {
            delete [] stack;
        }
        void reset();
        void push(int);
        void pop();
        int getTop();
        void getSize()
        {
            std::cout << size;
        }
};

#endif
```

The class implementation file:

```
#include "aStack.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void aStack::pop()
{
    if (top == -1)
        { cout << "Stack is already empty.\n";}
    stack[--top];

}

void aStack::push(int v)
{
    if (top == size)
        { cout << "Stack is full.\n";}
    stack[top++] = v;
}

void aStack::reset()
{
    top = -1;
}

int aStack::getTop()
{
    return top;
}
```

Here is the main program

```
#include <iostream>
#include "aStack.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    string equation {"35+1*"};
    int op, count = 0, *oparray, result;
    aStack stack(equation.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < equation.length(); i++)
        {
            if (isdigit(equation[i]))
            {

                stack.push(equation[i]);
                count++;
            }
            else 
                {
                    oparray = new int [count];
                    for (int o = 0; o < count; o++) 
                        {
                            oparray[o] = stack.getTop();
                            stack.pop();
                        }
                    switch(equation[i])
                        {
                            case '+':
                                for (int i =0; i < count; i++)
                                    {
                                        op += oparray[i];
                                        count--;
                                    }
                                stack.push(op);
                                break;


                            case '-':
                                for (int i =0; i < count; i++)
                                    {
                                        op-=oparray[i];
                                        count--;
                                    }
                                stack.push(op);
                                break;
                            case '*':
                                for (int i =0; i < count; i++)
                                    {
                                        op*=oparray[i];
                                        count--;
                                    }
                                stack.push(op);
                                break;
                            case '/':
                                for (int i =0; i < count; i++)
                                    {
                                        op/=oparray[i];
                                        count--;
                                    }
                                stack.push(op);
                                break;
                        }
                    delete [] oparray;
                }
        }
    result = stack.getTop();
    cout << result;
}
```

I know I should not use the "using namespace std;", I was in a hurry.  I doubt that would be the cause of my problems.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When it crashes, do you get any message?  If so, please include that in your post.

Comment: Unrelated: `Stack` violates [the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Have you done any of your own debugging to determine **where/when** the crash happens?

Comment: Does the rest of your program work if you replace your home made `aStack` with `std::stack`?

Comment: What, do you think, happens in `stack[top++] = v;` when `top == -1`?

Comment: Also note your stack's `getTop` method is returning the top **index**, rather than the top **value** in the stack. It should probably be `return stack[top];` instead of `return top;`

Comment: I just get the standard windows "program.exe has stopped working".  I get no warnings from the compiler.

Comment: *I just get the standard windows "program.exe has stopped working* -- Which means your program has bugs that cause such an error.

Comment: Similar to what @AlgirdasPreidžius mentioned, what do you think happens in `stack[--top];` when `top == 0`? Also, why are you accessing `stack` there at all?

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With a debugger you can run the program at your own pace, watching what the program does as it does it. You advance the program by stepping or with breakpoints to the spot you want to investigate more closely, and then start stepping, keeping an eye out for where the program does the unexpected. The unexpected is usually a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack class has miscellaneous problems already pointed out in the comments. With those fixed, only a few bugs in the main program remained.

I've used a `std::unique_ptr<>` in your array instead of a raw pointer and disabled move semantics so it's neither copyable (because of the `unique_ptr`) nor moveable.

I also added throwing exceptions if you try to access the stack out of bounds.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <cstddef>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class aStack {
public:
    using value_type = T;

    explicit aStack(size_t c) :
        cap(c), stored(0), stack(std::make_unique<value_type[]>(cap)) {}

    aStack(aStack&&) = delete;  // moving disabled

    void reset() noexcept { stored = 0; }

    void push(const value_type& v) {
        if(stored == cap) throw std::runtime_error("stack is full");
        stack[stored++] = v;
    }
    void push(value_type&& v) {
        if(stored == cap) throw std::runtime_error("stack is full");
        stack[stored++] = std::move(v);
    }
    value_type& pop() {
        if(stored == 0) throw std::runtime_error("stack is empty");
        return stack[--stored];
    }
    [[nodiscard]] const value_type& top() const {
        if(stored == 0) throw std::runtime_error("stack is empty");
        return stack[stored - 1];
    }
    [[nodiscard]] value_type& top() {
        if(stored == 0) throw std::runtime_error("stack is empty");
        return stack[stored - 1];
    }
    [[nodiscard]] size_t capability() const noexcept { return cap; }
    [[nodiscard]] size_t size() const noexcept { return stored; }

private:
    size_t cap, stored;
    std::unique_ptr<value_type[]> stack;
};
```

When it comes to the main program, the major problem was that you forgot to convert the ASCII value of each digit into an integer.
Another problem was the `op` calculation. You kept the value from the last iteration instead of grabbing a new value from the stack. There was also an extra allocation of memory that was unnecessary so I removed that. You also had *shadowing* variables, which didn't cause any error, but makes it really hard to read the code.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "USAGE: " << argv[0] << " <equation>\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::string equation(argv[1]);
    try {
        int op, result;
        aStack<int> stack(equation.length());

        for(size_t ei = 0; ei < equation.length(); ++ei) {
            if(std::isdigit(equation[ei])) {
                stack.push(equation[ei] - '0'); // from ASCII to digit
            } else {
                op = stack.pop();               // start with what's on the stack
                switch(equation[ei]) {
                case '+':
                    while(stack.size()) {
                        op += stack.pop();
                    }
                    stack.push(op);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    while(stack.size()) {
                        op -= stack.pop();
                    }
                    stack.push(op);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    while(stack.size()) {
                        op *= stack.pop();
                    }
                    stack.push(op);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    while(stack.size()) {
                        op /= stack.pop();
                    }
                    stack.push(op);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw std::runtime_error("invalid operation");
                }
            }
        }
        result = stack.pop();
        if(stack.size() != 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("stack not empty when calculation ended");

        std::cout << result << '\n';
    } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```